# change the style of a checkbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I need to change the appearance(styling) of a check box if it is checked so that it shows up on the page better.  Each checkbox has a unique id that is generated with ajax when the table is populated.  I am able to have a price field outlined in the same table by using this code:

```
function hiLight() {
$('#guides td.price').each(function() { 
     if ( $(this).html()!= '')
    {
        $(this).css('border', '3px solid red');
     }
});
```

and tried to use an amended portion for the check box:

```
$('#guides :checkbox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
        $(this).css('border', '3px solid red');
    }
 });
}//END OF HILIGHT FUNCTION
```

I know that it is going into the checkbox function since I used an alert to see if it was.  I think it is`$(this)` that is causing it not to know what to format since in the alert I used  `alert($(this))` and got back `[object] [object]` Is this even possible without using a plug in? If so, can someone please point me in the right direction

Comment: why don't you just do it in pure css?

Comment: I don't want every checkbox (there are about 30+ on the page) to be highlighted, just the checked ones.

Comment: Which you can do in CSS: `#guides input[type="checkbox"]:checked { outline: 3px solid red; }`

Comment: ok, how can I do that? and it needs to change everytime a box gets checked.  That is why I was using jquery to do it.

Comment: I tried your idea, didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you do not need JavaScript to style an input. 
Second, checkboxes do not have a border, but you can use outline.

```css
#guides input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="guides">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know I had to use outline.  that was the trick.  Thanks.